# How to have colored function calls in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Function calls in jupyter notebook are not colored unlike github codes.
Consider the figure where the github codes have colored .add_argument()  function whereas in jupyter notebook it is not. How to make it colored so that it is visually easy to code.

[image]

Comment: You could give JupyterLab a go, they are colored there (you could try out JupyterLab-classic if you prefer the old look).

Comment: Ok that helps.. I wil give it a try